# What is the right way to dubug context cancellation for a grpc call?

Tags: go, grpc, go-gin

I am working on an go application, that uses gin to serve the rest APIs.
I 4 of my handler functions for the APIs call a goroutine which makes a gRPC call. A strange thing i see, all the grpc calls for one of the handler fails with `context cancelled` while the other 3 succeed.

Looking at the logs, i noticed that my API returns before the goroutine is executed. Could it be possible that gin cancels the context after the API returns?

The context is propagated from the handler function to the goroutine through a couple of intermediate calls.

The error that i see is `rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

How can i debug this? Does gin cancel the context once it returns the response?

Answer (score 0):

> Does gin cancel the context once it returns the response?

The [docs for `Request.Context()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Context) (gin [uses `http.Request`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context)) say:

> For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2), or when the ServeHTTP method returns.

So, yes, the context is closed when your handler (effectively the ServeHTTP method) returns (see [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/net/http/server.go;l=1913;drc=c61d322d5f9e3fcffa4c523892af432dca030c12)). The context would also be cancelled if the connection dropped for another reason (network issue, or even your server shutting down).

The right way to handle this really depends upon what you want to achieve:

- In many cases the correct behaviour is to cancel the RPC calls when the context is cancelled. For example if you are retrieving info needed to fulfil the request then cancelling those requests may save resources.
- If you are triggering calls that must complete then pass in a `context.Background()` (or another context not directly tied to the request).

> How can i debug this?

Look at why your handler is returning before all RPC calls complete; if that is what you want then you will need to use a different context (but remember this probably means you are returning an OK response code when you don't actually know yet if the entire process will be successful).